# How should i get data from my private sql server, when my hosting doesnt allow remote connections?

Tags: php, database-connection

I have one.com as my hosting provider.

I will build a webap that will fetch data from my local sql server and publish it on my webpage hosted by one.com

one.com does not allow remote connections.
I´ve tried this:

```
//BUILD CONNECTION ARRAY
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,
                     "PWD"=>$pwd,
                     "Database"=>$databaseName);

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


//TEST CONNECTION
if( $conn ) {
echo "Connection established.<br />";

}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

This wont work because sqlsrv_connect isn´t accepted in php.ini

Is there any other way i can fetch my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't connect if hosting "does not allow remote connections"

But you can send requests via cURL and manage the database

Comment: Tell me more about cURL? The webhosting also mentioned json_request?!

Comment: curl supports json. more info https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).